# How to find an object, where element in an array does not match another field in that schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose 4.13.11 and am trying to find an element in an array where the 'last_message_read.messageId' does not equal the 'last_message field'. Here is the schema I am working with:

```
conversationSchema = new Schema{(
 last_message: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Message"},
    members: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
    }],
 last_message_read: [{
    user_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    message: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Message"}
  }], 
)}
```

And this is my attempted query:

```
const user_id = ObjectId();
conversationModel.find(
            {members: user_id},
            { $expr: { $where : "this.last_message != this.last_message_read.$.message && this.last_message_read.$.user_id == user_id"} },
            function(err, conversations){})
```

The problem is however I could not find anywhere in the docs that allowed such as a query and the closest I got was using $expr and $where. For example I am not sure I can include the && operation nor the user_id inside the quote.

Any thoughts of how to  perform this type of query would be great. Thanks.